# The components only load at the second refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am getting some data for videos, it renders well at first, but when refreshing the page all my components lose the information and they turn blank

I've tried different ways to approach the request, different life hooks and try catchs

```
mounted() {
    this.getVideos()
  },


methods: {
  async getVideos(){
    try {
      this.videosData = await this.$services.videoApi.getVideoData(
        param1,
        param2
      )
      this.groups = await this.getGroups(this.videosData)
      this.selectedGroup = this.groups[0]
      this.activeVideo = this.videosData.body.result.videos[0]
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
       this.downloadsError = true
    }
  }
},
 getGroups(videosData) {
      const groups = []
      videosData.body.result.videos.forEach(video => {
        if (!groups.includes(video.type.name)) {
          groups.push(video.type.name)
        }
      })
      return groups
    }
```

As previously said, at first it loads all the information just fine, it shows all the videos and groups, but when refreshing the page, it loses the videos and throws the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

line:

```
  videosData.body.result.videos.forEach(function (video) {
```

Comment: Because you're fetching your data over the network when the page loads. The data you are render is not available when the page loads or before you make the request.

Comment: Yeah, but using v-if won't render either

  <div v-if="videosData">

Comment: Can I see  your render method? The DOM would just flash.

Comment: I solved it, it was everything ok, my problem was with a nuxt-link which wasn't binding correctly